# Copying "live usb" install from USB stick to portable Hard Drive

Tags: hard-disk, live-usb, bootable

I have a bootable install of Linux Mint on a usb stick (ie a "live usb" install). It has a writable partition so that i can have persistence between one session and the next.

I've copied off the sdb1 and sdb2 partition files from the usb stick onto my laptop.  What i'd like to do now is to do the same thing but with a portable usb hard drive, using the sdb1 and sdb2 files i have from my original install, ie to clone the install onto a portable hard disk drive.

Is it as simple as formatting the disk to have the same format, and two partitions, and then just importing the partition files onto the new drive?  Obviously i could try this but i haven't actually bought the drive yet and wanted to know about any gotchas before i actually go and buy it.

thanks, Max

Comment: Assuming that the usb stick is `/dev/sdb` and the portable drive is `/dev/sdc`, you could try `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc` but then you would need to resize `/dev/sdc` with parted to maximize on the space. this should work but the only issue is going to be space on `/dev/sdc` since the usb stick is most likely smaller. But again, parted should fix that.